# Concat csv files and strip the header

Tags: unix, csv, sed, concatenation, tail

I have n number of csv files that I will need to concatenate. The issue is I need to remove the header file from each one.

I have tried using these
tail -n +2 $INPUT_FILE_PATH/$FILE > $NEW_INPUT_FILE_PATH

***This puts the filename and path in the newfile

==> /file path/filename1.csv <==

```
A, B, C, D 
E, F, G, H
```

==> /file path/filename2.csv <==

```
I, J, K, L 
M, N, O, P
```

I have tried

```
sed 1d $INPUT_FILE_PATH/$FILE > $NEW_INPUT_FILE_PATH
```

***Only removes the header from the first file.

```
A, B, C, D,
E, F, G, H
```

Header1, header2, header3, header4

```
I, J, K, L
M, N, O, P
```

How can I have the result be

```
A, B, C, D,
E, F, G, H
I, J, K, L
M, N, O, P
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `sed` for that:

```
 find /path/to/files -name '*.csv' -exec sed '1d' {} \;
```

Comment: I used that above, but it does not remove the header from the second file, only the first.

Comment: Oh yes, my fault! Changed the answer

Comment: That one gives EFGH and IJKL on the same line

Comment: Just updated it. :) I need a line break between them. It puts a comma between H & I

Comment: Tried with -maxdepth 1 added and the results are the same

Comment: That adds the header back

Comment: No, but I found the solution...grep -h -v 'beginning of line' fileName* >>Myfile.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR>1' file1 file2 ...
```